# Database connection and save_click

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, database-table

I have a sql database called Facturen (dutch for invoice) in the database there is a databasetable called Facturen (dutch for invoices).

Also I have a C# form (winforms) with a `datagridwiew` some `textboxes` and some `labels`. 
Also I have a `Button` and on the click event the following code.

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MACTARIS\MSSQL2014;Initial Catalog=Factuur;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*********")) ;
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Facturen (Klant, Adres, Postcode, Plaats, BTWnummer, Datum, Betalingswijze, BTWpercentage, Artikel, Aantal, Eenheidsprijs, TotaalexBTW, Totaalbedrag, Totaal_ex_BTW, BTW, Tebetalen) VALUES(@Klant,@Adres,@Postcode,@Plaats, @BTWnummer, @Datum, @Betalingswijze, @BTWpercentage, @Artikel, @Aantal, @Eenheidsprijs, @TotaalexBTW, @Korting, @Totaalbedrag, @Totaal_ex_BTW, @BTW, @Tebetalen)", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Klant", lblKlant.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adres", lblAdres.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", lblPostcode.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plaats", lblPlaats.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BTWnummer", lblBTWnummer.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", txtDatum.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Betalingswijze", cboBetalingswijze.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BTWpercentage", cboPercentage.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artikel", row.Cells[0].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aantal", row.Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eenheidsprijs", row.Cells[2].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotaalexBTW", row.Cells[3].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BTW", row.Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Korting", row.Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Totaalbedrag", row.Cells[6].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Totaal_ex_BTW", txtTotaalexBTW.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tebetalen", txtTebetalen.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Now when I click the `Button` to save to the database I get the following error  `Additional information: Invalid object name 'Facturen'.`

I'm 100% sure that the databasetable is called Facturen and I'm 100% sure that there is a database.

Comment: Is there any Schema you used for your table name or is resides in dbo schema? Also try to execute a select command and see if you have access to your database and table.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the database name in the connection string